# Tensorflow prefetching to multiple GPUs

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

When having a Tensorflow dataset and multiple GPUs it is beneficial to preload data to the multiple GPUs.

The only example I could find is in this [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/13610#issuecomment-411893139)

```
host_dataset_on_cpu = .....
multi_device_iterator = prefetching_ops.MultiDeviceIterator(host_dataset_on_cpu, devices=['/gpu:0', '/gpu:1'])
elem_on_gpu_0, elem_on_gpu_1 = multi_device_iterator.get_next()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(multi_device_iterator.initializer)
    elem_0 = sess.run(elem_on_gpu_0)
    elem_1 = sess.run(elem_on_gpu_1)
```

What I am wondering is:
- is it really necessary to have multiple calls to sess.run (one for each GPU?)
- Can this work with a configurable number of GPUs? (splits = multi_device_iterator.get_next())
- It seems like this MultiDeviceIterator is implemented, but can not be found in the documentation. Is it still under development?

Also when I try to implement this I get a lot of errors

> 2018-11-02 09:22:15.740637: W
>   tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1261] Unimplemented:
>   Unsupported object type list 2018-11-02 09:22:15.741142: W
>   tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1261] Unimplemented:
>   Unsupported object type list 2018-11-02 09:22:15.741670: W
>   tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1261] Unimplemented:
>   Unsupported object type list 2018-11-02 09:22:15.742512: W
>   tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1261] Unimplemented:
>   Unsupported object type list 2018-11-02 09:22:15.748161: W
>   tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1261] Unimplemented:
>   Unsupported object type list 2018-11-02 09:22:15.749587: W
>   tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1261] Unimplemented:
>   Unsupported object type list 2018-11-02 09:22:15.752334: W
>   tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1261] Unimplemented:
>   Unsupported object type list 2018-11-02 09:22:15.752756: W
>   tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1261] Unimplemented:
>   Unsupported object type list 2018-11-02 09:22:15.753581: W
>   tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1261] Unimplemented:
>   Unsupported object type list 2018-11-02 09:22:15.753974: W
>   tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1261] Unimplemented:
>   Unsupported object type list 2018-11-02 09:22:15.754434: W
>   tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1261] Unimplemented:
>   Unsupported

which seem not really helpful

Comment: i checked link to github source code thats mentioned there and it doesnt have anything related to MultiDeviceIterator. 
I checked in the github repo and found the [test file](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/301613ab83cd3fe0658d862bcb992e6124f62169/tensorflow/python/data/kernel_tests/multi_device_iterator_test.py) for this Iterator. It doesnt seem to have any tests for fetching data to multiple gpus as far as I can tell.
Anyways, for a workaround, you can check if [Tensorpack](https://tensorpack.readthedocs.io/tutorial/index.html#introduction) might be able to help?